# How to pass an arrayList to the AlertDialog fragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

So I have an `AlertDialog` which renders `MultiChoiceItemsList` and is as follows,

```
public class CustomDayRepeatFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public interface DayRepeatListner {
        void onFinishDayRepeatListner(List<String> days);
    }
    //List to save the result
    private ArrayList<String> selectedDays;
    String weekdays[];
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        selectedDays = new ArrayList<>();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        weekdays = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weekdays);
        Log.d("In dialog", "Custom");
        builder.setTitle("Select Days to Repeat")
                .setMultiChoiceItems(weekdays, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked) {
                            selectedDays.add(weekdays[which]);
                        } else if (selectedDays.contains(weekdays[which])) {
                            selectedDays.remove(String.valueOf(weekdays[which]));
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        for(int i = 0; i < selectedDays.size(); i++) {
                            Log.d("Selected Days", selectedDays.get(i));
                        }

                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

And I am calling it from my main activity as follows

```
 CustomDayRepeatFragment dialog = new CustomDayRepeatFragment();
 dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_REPEAT_SETTING);
```

However, I would like to send a `List<string>` to this `AlertDialog` and then make use of this list.

I am not able to figure out how to achieve it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: why not use just a standard setter?

Comment: When you say send a list<string> you mean send from alertDialog to your activity right?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi no from activity to alertDialog

Comment: The list is to save the choices?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Yeah the list will be to save the choices

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static newInstance method in your `CustomDayRepeatFragment` class and then call it from the `MainActivity` as follows. Here you can send the list as an argument

```
CustomDayRepeatFragment dialog = CustomDayRepeatFragment.newInstance(list);
 dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_REPEAT_SETTING);
```

Now in the `newInstance() method` of the `CustomDayRepeatFragment` class you can save the list as an argument in the `Bundle` as `bundle.putParcelableArrayList("list", list);` and then retrieve it from the bundle arguments in the `onCreateDialog() method` as `List<String> list = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("list");`

your newInstance and your onCreateDialog methods will look like

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        selectedDays = new ArrayList<>();


        List<String> list = (List<String>) getArguments().getStringArrayList("list");  // the list you pass as an argument

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        weekdays = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weekdays);
        Log.d("In dialog", "Custom");
        builder.setTitle("Select Days to Repeat")
                .setMultiChoiceItems(weekdays, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked) {
                            selectedDays.add(weekdays[which]);
                        } else if (selectedDays.contains(weekdays[which])) {
                            selectedDays.remove(String.valueOf(weekdays[which]));
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        for(int i = 0; i < selectedDays.size(); i++) {
                            Log.d("Selected Days", selectedDays.get(i));
                        }

                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }

    //Creating a fragment instance class to pass the parameters
    public static CustomDayRepeatFragment newInstance(int groupPosition) {
        CustomDayRepeatFragment fragment = new CustomDayRepeatFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArrayList("list", (ArrayList<String>)list);

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: Edited the code, you need to typecast to ArrayList<String> while saving and  to List<String> while retriving